# Selection list 2 depends on selection list 1

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm making an interface and I've to use two selection lists, where the input in selection list 1 will decide the options for selection list 2.

**Exmaple:**

Selection list one has: `GSM, CDMA`

then,

if user selects `GSM`, he should see `CRICKET, RADIO, HOROSCOPE` in selection `list 2`. Or if user selects `CDMA`, he should see `COMBO OFFER, VOICE CHAT, WIN THE DREAM` in selection `list 2`

can anybody please help me out?

THIS IS THE CODE

```
<tr>
<td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SERVICE :</b></font> </td>
<td><select name="service" >
<option value="GSM">GSM</option>
<option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
<option value="VIRGIN MOBILE">VIRGIN MOBILE</option>
</select>
</td>


<td style="color:white"> <font size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VAS :</b></font> </td>
<td><select name="service" >
<option value="COMBO OFFER">COMBO OFFER</option>
<option value="COMBO OFFER CDMA">COMBO OFFER CDMA</option>
<option value="WIN THE DREAM">WIN THE DREAM</option>
<option value="VOICE CHAT">VOICE CHAT</option>
<option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
<option value="ASTRO">ASTRO</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

lets say, I require COMBO OFFER, WIN THE DREAM and CRICKET in the second list if GSM is selected in the 1st selection list.
and COMBO OFFER CDMA, VOICE CHAT and ASTRO if CDMA is selected in the 1st list 
how do we do it?

Comment: Where do your comboboxes get their items from? Dynamically while execution or predefined, somewhere in the code?

Comment: @ifLoop  predefined in the code

Comment: May we see some of your code? That would help us to help you properly and not by creating examples

Comment: icannot answer my own question and the code is exceeding the word limit

Comment: i'm unab;e to enter the code properly in the comments,

Comment: you need to use javascripts for dynamically changing values of select element.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the second list's items in an array of arrays of strings:

```
String[][] listContent = {
        {"CRICKET", "RADIO", "HOROSCOPE"},
        {"COMBO OFFER", "VOICE CHAT", "WIN THE DREAM"},
};
```

Your first list then needs to update the second's list items like so:

```
list1.addActionListener(e -> {
    list2.removeAllItems();
    Stream.of(listContent[list1.getSelectedIndex()]).forEach(list2::addItem);
});
```

An example (test):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] listContent = {
            {"CRICKET", "RADIO", "HOROSCOPE"},
            {"COMBO OFFER", "VOICE CHAT", "WIN THE DREAM"},
    };

    JFrame wnd = new JFrame();
    wnd.setLocation(200, 200);
    wnd.setSize(200, 120);
    wnd.setLayout(null);
    wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JComboBox<String> list1 = new JComboBox<>();
    list1.setLocation(10, 10);
    list1.setSize(150, 25);
    wnd.add(list1);

    JComboBox<String> list2 = new JComboBox<>();
    list2.setLocation(10, 40);
    list2.setSize(150, 25);
    wnd.add(list2);

    wnd.setVisible(true);

    list1.addItem("GSM");
    list1.addItem("CDMA");

    list1.addActionListener(e -> {
        list2.removeAllItems();
        Stream.of(listContent[list1.getSelectedIndex()]).forEach(list2::addItem);
    });
}
```

Comment: it's not like this, i want to show you the code but how do i do it in the comments?

Comment: @learner Post it somewhere else (e.g. on [Pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com) ) and share the link.

Comment: as an exmaplen to that code lets say, we require COMBO OFFER, WIN THE DREAM and CRICKET in the second list if GSM is selected in the 1st selection list

Comment: @happy, yes, i just did it.